# How to transfer money directly from US to home loan account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, india

Can we transfer money from US directly to the home loan account? Do we have any tax implications in US or in India? I don't have an NRE/NRO account and want to transfer directly to Home loan account.  Please explain.

Comment: Are you a citizen of India with NRI status? Or are you a US citizen? If not, are you a US _tax resident_ (this has nothing to do with your _visa_ status; you might have a nonimmigrant visa but still be classified as a _resident_ for _tax_ purposes). If you _are_ a US tax resident, have you been declaring _all_ your income in India to the IRS as required and filing FATCA reports with the US Treasury each year reporting foreign assets? Is your home loan account a _bank_ account from which you make EMI payments every month?

Comment: I am NRI and not the US citizen. I have a savin account from which my EMI payment goes to Loan account. But I  can pay directly to loan account my prepayment. So was asking can I do that and is there any tax implication.  I have not declared FATCa..yet

Answer (score 1):

As per FEMA (Foreign Exchange Management Act) regulations, NRI can't hold savings account in India. Please get this converted to NRO. Can be done remotely.

Most banks don't allow direct deposit into loan account. Check with your bank if they allow.

There is no fax implications in India.

You need to declare this in your US tax returns.

It is advisable to repay the loan account via NRE account as repatriation of funds on sale is easier